# preg_match never passes

Tags: php, preg-match

My account creation script's name input is validated with a `preg_match` as the field is only allowed to have either Latin *or* Cyrillic characters (in other words, it cannot have both), however, no matter what the name field contains, the `preg_match` condition is never satisfied. So far I've tried three possible variations of the code:

```
if (!(preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i',$_POST['name']) || preg_match('/^[а-я]$/i',$_POST['name']))) back('The message');

if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]$/i',$_POST['name']) &&  !preg_match('/^[а-я]$/i',$_POST['name'])) back('The message');
```

and one that attempts to stuff both the preg matches into one.

Could anyone please help me out in fixing this issue?

Comment: Try enabling utf mode in preg? `.../iu`

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the reply, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are limiting the name to exactly one character:

```
/^[a-z]$/i
```

Change it to:

```
/^[a-z]+$/i
```

and

```
/^[а-я]+$/i
```

Comment: Since I've spend a fair amount of time learning regular expressions some time ago, it's actually embarrassing that I haven't noticed this; must be getting tired. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's abstract those `preg_match` functions into the names `is_latin` and `is_cyrillic` for readability. You're then looking for the logic:

```
if is_latin xor is_cyrillic     -> OK
else                            -> not OK
```

Or, inverted:

```
if !(is_latin xor is_cyrillic)  -> not OK
```

`xor` is only true if one is `true` and the other `false`.

Additionally, your regexen match only a single character. You'll want `/^[a-z]+$/i` to match a whole word. Further, to match a non-latin word/regex, you need to use the `u` modifier like `/^[а-я]+$/iu` and make sure your source code and the subject are encoded in UTF-8. So:

```
if (!(preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $_POST['name']) xor preg_match('/^[а-я]+$/iu', $_POST['name']))) {
    // error
}
```

You can even shorten this into one regex:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([a-z]+|[а-я]+)$/iu', $_POST['name'])) {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also assert both in one regex:

```
if (!preg_match('/ ^[a-z]+$ | ^[\p{Cyrillic}]+$ /ixu',$_POST['name'])) {
```

Note the two `|` alternatives, bot constrained by `^` and `$`.

There is also `\p{Latin}`, not just `\p{Cyrillic}` for matching the complete character range.

Answer (score 0):

With your condition, if the first "if" does not pass, the second won't either because they are equivalent `!(A or B) <=> !A && !B` what you want is a xor

Moreover, you just test only one character with your "preg match" here.

your condition should be

```
if( preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/iu',$_POST['name']) xor preg_match('/^[а-я]+$/iu',$_POST['name']){

   // do what you want

  }
```

Comment: That's why I said that these are but two variations of how I tried to remedy this problem.